# maximum number of filegroups in a database?

Tags: sql-server

maximum number of filegroups in a database?

Answer (score 3):

[For Sql Server 2008](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143432.aspx)

> Filegroups per database - 32,767

Answer (score 1):

A simple search reveals - 32,767. See the following chart for SQL Server capacity information.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143432.aspx